# MySQL parameterized query is functioning like it is not parameterized in C# application

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I keep getting this error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Feature: SecurityTesting @mytag Scenario: SQL Injection Given I visit ' at line 1'

The parameter Gherkin is the one causing the query to fail. I have tried both ? and @ as parameter prefixes and nothing changes.

Here's my code:

```
string CommandText = " INSERT INTO Feature(`Path`, Gherkin, RepoID, `Name`, Updated) VALUES (?Path,  ?Gherkin , ?RepoID, ?Name, ?Updated) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Gherkin = VALUES(?Gherkin); ";


       

            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TAF_DB"].ConnectionString;
                using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand())
                {

                    var gherkinParam = new MySqlParameter("Gherkin", test.Gherkin);
                    //var gherkinParam = new MySqlParameter("Gherkin", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    var pathParam = new MySqlParameter("Path", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    var RepoIDParam = new MySqlParameter("RepoID", MySqlDbType.Int64);
                    var nameParam = new MySqlParameter("Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    var updatedParam = new MySqlParameter("Updated", MySqlDbType.VarChar);

                    gherkinParam.Value = test.Gherkin;
                    command.Parameters.Add(gherkinParam);
                    pathParam.Value = test.Path;
                    command.Parameters.Add(pathParam);
                    RepoIDParam.Value = test.RepoID;

                    command.Parameters.Add(RepoIDParam);
                    nameParam.Value = test.Name;

                    command.Parameters.Add(nameParam);
                    updatedParam.Value = test.Updated;
                    command.Parameters.Add(updatedParam);

                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = CommandText;
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();

                }
            }
```

Comment: Some side tips: `command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;` is not necessary, it's the default. `connection.Close();` also not necessary, `using` will do that. You can use construcotr parameters to shorten to `using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TAF_DB"].ConnectionString)) using (var command = new MySqlCommand(CommandText, connection)) {...` you can also shorten the parameters to `command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Gherkin", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = test.Gherkin;` etc. You can use a multi-line string for the command-text with `@"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the name of the column `Gherkin` inside the function [`VALUES()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) and not the named parameter `?Gherkin`:

```
UPDATE Gherkin = VALUES(Gherkin)
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick for the last part of the statement but I still had to have a @ or ? prefix for the first 'VALUES" part or else the value was just always "Gherkin".

Comment: @Benny of course you have to use ?Gherkin inside the VALUES list. My answer is about the VALUES() function in the UPDATE statement.